# Selenium : not able to detect a popup(alert) on chrome

Tags: python, selenium, popup, selenium-chromedriver, alert

[This is screnshot of popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeY6Q.jpg)I was trying to automate WhatsApp but when I try to visit [WhatsApp api](https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=1234567890&text=Hi%20There) it gives an alert to open another link. 
I tried to close it using selenium but it doesn't detect the alert and there is no error or anything

```
def sendmesssage():
phone = "899928555"
url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+911234567890&text=Hi%20There"
browser.get(url)
while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present()).dismiss()
        print("found")
        alert = browser.switch_to.alert
        print(alert.text)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="action-button"]').click()
        return;
    except :
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I mistake you are doing is that you are you have to use the number along with the country code. Include the country code and try again ex for India it is +91 so change the phone no to +91899928555 It should work fine. and what pop is it. A ad popup or a dialog box.

Comment: thats not what im asking. i just want that popup alert to open URL to be canceled. and your answer definately not relevent. but ill modify the question

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the popup alert?

Comment: check now.added in the question